# 403 forbidden error page with Google Wallet Online Commerce

Tags: javascript, google-api

i call google.wallet.online.authorize() method to determine if user is pre authorized to Google Wallet Online Commerce payment system. When it returns null, the Google wallet buy button page displayed on the page.

After clicking the buy button the popup window opens, if i login with credentials it redirect to 403 Forbidden error page.

Any help would be appreciated !
Thanks,
Srinivas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found that the demo version has the same problem

See the demo at : https://developers.google.com/wallet-online/

After clicking the "Buy with Google Wallet" button a popup window appears and after login 403 page will appear.

I think the problem is there with google side.